# Best way to represent multi-hierarchy menu in SQL with "unlimited" children?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to create a multi-layer menu with no restriction on how far it can branch out - e.g. Food->Fruits->Round Shape->color etc...

I am not sure how to represent the relationship in SQL and also am not sure how to query the data.

I thought about doing:

> MainMenu:
>   ID:ChildID:Name:URL:PermissionID:etc.
>
> SubMenu:
>   PID:ChildID:Name:URL:PermissionID:etc.

I think if the submenu has additional submenus, its children would be another item in the SubMenu table, and that should work? The PermissionID is used to determine if the Menu item can be accessed by a UserGroup.

I am not sure about the SQL query since i am a little green on it. I know in the end I am feeding UserGroup's PermissionIDs to the SQL to get all the Menu and Submenu from the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Storing hierachical data in RDBMS is not a good idea. Either you can use document based frameworks like Elastic https://www.elastic.co/ which stores data in JSON document format or you can use hierachical JSON in varchar column in RDBMS.

Comment: can you give an example for the JSON in varchar column? wouldnt it be hard to keep track to have a long json? if i make any change to a particular menu i need to change many JSON in the varchar column?

Comment: @shaselai definitely you'll have to maintain JSON and it will give you ease to extend your hierarchy to any level but then it shouldn't be exceeding varchar limit. Converting from JSON to Object or Vice-versa can be done using **gson** or **jackson** easily in Java. And if you are displaying menu on browser JSON would be easy to pass. You can store data like `{"food":"fruit","name":"orange","shape":"round","colur":"orange"}`. Maintaing this tree kind of hierarchi would be difficult to maintain in RDBMS and it will increase JOIN cost and hence degraded performance.

Comment: Hmm,  but if permissions comes into play wouldnt it make this really murkey?

Comment: Hmm,  but if permissions comes into play wouldnt it make this really murky? 
For example:
Menu->food(1.Fruit,2.Veg,3.Meat)->Fruit->Oranges,Apples,Pears etc.
Now if only certain users can see Fruit->oranges vs Fruit->apples,pears. how would i represent that in JSON? It could be many combinations.

My end goal is to have the menu item and submenuitems be available to people with different permissions so that even under same menu, the items can be seen are different. i dont see how using JSON can help with this?